# CoreData: Sort and Section on Relationships

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have two questions about using Core Data. Taking the typical case of Employee and Department as an example. The Employee entity has a relationship field "deparment" as to-one to Department, and the Department entity has a relationship "employee" as to-many to Employee entity.

I would like to display all the employees in a TableView in sections of department's names. I think that the NSFetchedResultsController should use Employee as entity. I am not sure how to use Department's name as a sort criteria, since it is in an employee's relationship field department's name. Can you use "DepartmentName" as a sort and add this to Employee entity class as a method which will return department's name for a given employee?

The second question is the section name. I would like to use department names as sections. Can I use the above method as sectionKeyPath's value for the NSFethedResultsController?

Not sure if I am on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the sort key to be department.name for the sectionKey as well as the sort.  You can even sort first by department.name and then by the employee's name.

### update

The string "department.name" can be used both as the sort key in the `NSSortDescriptor` and as the section name in the construction of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

This is a part of Key Value Coding and highly recommend that you read up on it as there is a lot of power and flexibility lurking in there.

Comment: What is the "sectionKey"? or which class does it belong to? As your answer, so the "department.name" can be set to "sectionKey" parameter as a sort descriptor?